# SQL Server: collect values in an aggregation temporarily and re-use in the same query

Tags: sql-server, arrays, t-sql, aggregate-functions

How do I accumulate values in T-SQL? AFAIK there is no ARRAY type.
I want to re-use the values in the same query like demonstrated in this PostgreSQL example using [array_agg()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html).

```sql
SELECT a[1] || a[i] AS foo
     , a[2] || a[5] AS bar  -- assuming we have >= 5 rows for simplicity
FROM  (
    SELECT array_agg(text_col ORDER BY text_col) AS a
        , count(*)::int4 AS i
    FROM   tbl
    WHERE  id BETWEEN 10 AND 100
    ) sub;
```

How would I best solve this with **T-SQL**?
Best I could come up with are two CTE and subselects:

```sql
;WITH x AS (
   SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS rn
        , name AS a
   FROM   #t
   WHERE  id BETWEEN 10 AND 100
   )
, i AS (
   SELECT count(*) AS i
   FROM   x
   )
SELECT (SELECT a FROM x WHERE rn = 1) + (SELECT a FROM x WHERE rn = i) AS foo
     , (SELECT a FROM x WHERE rn = 2) + (SELECT a FROM x WHERE rn = 5) AS bar
FROM   i;
```

Test setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #t(
  id   INT PRIMARY KEY
, name NVARCHAR(100))
;

INSERT INTO #t VALUES
  ( 3, 'John')
, ( 5, 'Mary')
, ( 8, 'Michael')
, (13, 'Steve')
, (21, 'Jack')
, (34, 'Pete')
, (57, 'Ami')
, (88, 'Bob')
;
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: an array is called a table, a table variable, a temporary table or a cursor in tsql.

Comment: I have added the fourth solution (to my answer) that shows how to simulate ARRAY_AGG on SQL Server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit 1: I have added another solution that shows how to simulate ARRAY_AGG on SQL Server (the last answer).**

**Edit 2: For the solution number 4) I have added the third method for concatenation.**

I'm not sure I have I understood correctly your question.

a) Instead of using arrays in SQL Server I would use table variables or XML.

b) To concatenate strings (in this case) I would use `SELECT @var = @var + Name FROM tbl` statements or `XML xqueries`.

c) The solution based on CTEs and multiple subqueries (`WITH cte AS () FROM SELECT (SELECT * FROM cte.rn=1) + ()...`) will generates a lot of scans and logical reads.

Solutions:
1) Table variable + `SELECT @var = @var + Name FROM tbl`:

```
--Creating the "array"
DECLARE @Array TABLE
(
    Idx     INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Val     NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

WITH Base
AS
(
    SELECT  Val = t.name, 
            Idx = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.name ASC)
    FROM    #t t
    WHERE  t.id between 10 AND 100
)
INSERT  @Array (Idx, Val)
SELECT  b.Idx, b.Val
FROM    Base b;

--Concatenating all names
DECLARE @AllNames NVARCHAR(4000);
--”Reset”/Init @AllNames
SET     @AllNames = '';
--String concatenation
SELECT  @AllNames = @AllNames + ',' + a.Val
FROM    @Array a;
--Remove first char (',')
SELECT  @AllNames = STUFF(@AllNames, 1, 1, '');
--The final result
SELECT  @AllNames [Concatenating all names - using a table variable];
/*
Concatenating all names - using a table variable
------------------------------------------------
Ami,Bob,Jack,Pete,Steve
*/

--Concatenating Idx=2 and Idx=5
--”Reset” @AllNames value
SET     @AllNames = '';
--String concatenation
SELECT  @AllNames = @AllNames + ',' + a.Val
FROM    @Array a
WHERE   a.Idx IN (2,5) --or a.Idx IN (2, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Array))
ORDER BY a.Idx ASC;
--Remove first char (',')
SELECT  @AllNames = STUFF(@AllNames, 1, 1, '');
--The final result
SELECT  @AllNames [Concatenating Idx=2 and Idx=5 - using a table variable];
/*
Concatenating Idx=2 and Idx=5 - using a table variable
------------------------------------------------------
Bob,Steve
*/
```

2) Table variable + `PIVOT`:

```
--Concatenating a finite number of elements (names)
SELECT   pvt.[1] + ',' + pvt.[0]    AS [PIVOT Concat_1_and_i(0)]
        ,pvt.[2] + ',' + pvt.[5]    AS [PIVOT Concat_2_and_5]
        ,pvt.*
FROM    
(
        SELECT  a.Idx, a.Val
        FROM    @Array a
        WHERE   a.Idx IN (1,2,5)
        UNION ALL   
        SELECT  0, a.Val --The last element has Idx=0
        FROM    @Array a
        WHERE   a.Idx = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Array)
) src
PIVOT   (MAX(src.Val) FOR src.Idx IN ([1], [2], [5], [0])) pvt;
/*
PIVOT Concat_1_and_i(0) PIVOT Concat_2_and_5
----------------------- --------------------
Ami,Steve               Bob,Steve           
*/
```

3) XML + XQuery:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
GO

DECLARE @x XML;
;WITH Base
AS
(
    SELECT  Val = t.name, 
            Idx = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.name ASC)
    FROM    #t t
    WHERE   t.id BETWEEN 10 AND 100
)
SELECT  @x = 
(
    SELECT   b.Idx  AS [@Idx]
            ,b.Val  AS [text()]
    FROM    Base b
    FOR XML PATH('Element'), ROOT('Array')
);
/* @x content
<Array>
  <Element Idx="1">Ami</Element>
  <Element Idx="2">Bob</Element>
  <Element Idx="3">Jack</Element>
  <Element Idx="4">Pete</Element>
  <Element Idx="5">Steve</Element>
</Array>
*/

--Concatenating all names (the result is XML, so a cast is needed)
DECLARE @r XML; --XML result
SELECT  @r=@x.query('
(: $e = array element :)
for $e in (//Array/Element)
    return string($e)
');
SELECT  REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), @r), ' ', ',') AS [Concatenating all names - using XML];
/*
Concatenating all names - using XML
-----------------------------------
Ami,Bob,Jack,Pete,Steve
*/

--Concatenating Idx=1 and all names
SELECT  @r=@x.query('
(: $e = array element :)
for $e in (//Array/Element[@Idx=1], //Array/Element)
    return string($e)
');
SELECT  REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), @r), ' ', ',') AS [Concatenating Idx=1 and all names - using XML];
/*
Concatenating Idx=1 and all names - using XML
---------------------------------------------
Ami,Ami,Bob,Jack,Pete,Steve
*/

--Concatenating Idx=1 and i(last name)
DECLARE @i INT;
SELECT  @r=@x.query('
(: $e = array element :)
for $e in (//Array/Element[@Idx=1], //Array/Element[@Idx=count(//Array/Element)])
    return string($e)
');
SELECT  REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), @r), ' ', ',') AS [Concatenating Idx=1 and i(last name) - using XML];
/*
Concatenating Idx=1 and i(last name) - using XML
------------------------------------------------
Ami,Steve
*/


--Concatenating Idx=2 and Idx=5
SELECT  @r=@x.query('
(: $e = array element :)
for $e in (//Array/Element[@Idx=2], //Array/Element[@Idx=5])
    return string($e)
');
SELECT  REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), @r), ' ', ',') AS [Concatenating Idx=2 and Idx=5 - using XML (method 1)];
/*
Concatenating Idx=2 and Idx=5 - using XML (method 1)
----------------------------------------------------
Bob,Steve
*/

--Concatenating Idx=2 and Idx=5
SELECT  @x.value('(//Array/Element)[@Idx=2][1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')
        + ','
        + @x.value('(//Array/Element)[@Idx=5][1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS [Concatenating Idx=2 and Idx=5 - using XML (method 2)];;
/*
Concatenating Idx=2 and Idx=5 - using XML (method 2)
----------------------------------------------------
Bob,Steve
*/
```

**4) If the question is how to simulate `ARRAY_AGG` on SQL Server then, one answer might be: by using XML.**
Example:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
GO

DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
     Id         INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,GroupID    INT NOT NULL
    ,Name       NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Test (Id, GroupID, Name)
VALUES
 (3 , 1, 'John')
,(5 , 1, 'Mary')
,(8 , 1, 'Michael')
,(13, 1, 'Steve')
,(21, 1, 'Jack')
,(34, 2, 'Pete')
,(57, 2, 'Ami')
,(88, 2, 'Bob');

WITH BaseQuery
AS
(
        SELECT  a.GroupID, a.Name
        FROM    @Test a
        WHERE   a.Id BETWEEN 10 AND 100 
)
SELECT  x.*
        , CONVERT(XML,x.SQLServer_Array_Agg).query
        ('
        for $e in (//Array/Element[@Idx=1], //Array/Element[@Idx=count(//Array/Element)])
            return string($e)
        ') AS [Concat Idx=1 and Idx=i (method 1)]
        , CONVERT(XML,x.SQLServer_Array_Agg).query('
            let $a :=  string((//Array/Element[@Idx=1])[1])
            let $b :=  string((//Array/Element[@Idx=count(//Array/Element)])[1])
            let $c :=  concat($a , "," , $b) (: " is used as a string delimiter :)
            return $c
        ') AS [Concat Idx=1 and Idx=i (method 2)]
        , CONVERT(XML,x.SQLServer_Array_Agg).query
        ('
        for $e in (//Array/Element[@Idx=(1,count(//Array/Element))])
            return string($e)
        ') AS [Concat Idx=1 and Idx=i (method 3)]
FROM
(
    SELECT  a.GroupID
        ,(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY b.Name) AS [@Idx]
                ,b.Name AS [text()]
        FROM    BaseQuery b
        WHERE   a.GroupID = b.GroupID 
        ORDER BY b.Name
        FOR XML PATH('Element'), ROOT('Array') ) AS SQLServer_Array_Agg
    FROM    BaseQuery a
    GROUP BY a.GroupID
) x;
```

Results:

```
GroupID SQLServer_Array_Agg                                                                                        Concat Idx=1 and Idx=i (method 1) Concat Idx=1 and Idx=i (method 2) Concat Idx=1 and Idx=i (method 3)
------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------- --------------------------------- ---------------------------------
1       <Array><Element Idx="1">Jack</Element><Element Idx="2">Steve</Element></Array>                             Jack Steve                        Jack,Steve                        Jack Steve
2       <Array><Element Idx="1">Ami</Element><Element Idx="2">Bob</Element><Element Idx="3">Pete</Element></Array> Ami Pete                          Ami,Pete                          Ami Pete
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Generally, the performance for `[N]VARCHAR(max)` data types is lower than for `[N]VARCHAR(n)` data types [(source)](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/22/performance-comparison-of-varcharmax-vs-varcharn/).

Answer (score 2):

If you're just collecting some values to reuse, try a table variable rather than a temp table

```
DECLARE @t TABLE 
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT @t VALUES (3 , 'John')
-- etc
```

The table variable is in-memory only, instead of going in the tempdb database like a temp table does.

Check [Should I use a #temp table or table variable](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html) for more information.

Comment: While not actually answering my question (aggregate and re-use in the same query), this is interesting. Very informative link.

Comment: "Under memory pressure, the pages belonging to a table variable can be pushed out to tempdb."[(source)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2008/03/30/sql-server-table-variable-vs-local-temporary-table.aspx#comments)

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Thank you, I was not aware - that is good to know.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this helps, but you can always...

```
select * into #MyTempTable from SomeTable
```