# PostgreSQL - SQL state: 42601 syntax error

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, bulkinsert, dynamic-sql

I would like to know how to use a dynamic query inside a function. I've tried lots of ways, however, when I try to compile my function a message SQL 42601 is displayed.

The code that I use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prc_tst_bulk(sql text)
RETURNS TABLE (name text, rowcount integer) AS 
$$
BEGIN
  WITH v_tb_person AS (return query execute sql)
  select name, count(*) from v_tb_person where nome like '%a%' group by name
  union
  select name, count(*) from v_tb_person where gender = 1 group by name;
END     
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Error message I receive:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "return"
LINE 5:     WITH v_tb_person AS (return query execute sql)
```

I tried using:

```
WITH v_tb_person AS (execute sql)

WITH v_tb_person AS (query execute)

WITH v_tb_person AS (return query execute)
```

What is wrong? How can I solve this problem?

Its a question related to [PostgreSQL equivalent of Oracle “bulk collect”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289225/postgresql-equivalent-of-oracle-bulk-collect/16290228?noredirect=1#comment23320001_16290228)

Comment: This is clearly plpgsql syntax. What is the `[Oracle]` tag doing here?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Previous question was about translating PL/SQL to PL/PgSQL, so probably carried that over. I've removed the tag.

Comment: One thing that can be well worth trying is the documentation. A lot of effort goes into the PostgreSQL (and PL/PgSQL) documentation. In this case, you'll want to start with [Dynamic statements in PL/PgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your function would work like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prc_tst_bulk(sql text)
  RETURNS TABLE (name text, rowcount int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
   WITH v_tb_person AS (' || sql || $x$)
   SELECT name, count(*)::int FROM v_tb_person WHERE nome LIKE '%a%' GROUP BY name
   UNION
   SELECT name, count(*)::int FROM v_tb_person WHERE gender = 1 GROUP BY name$x$;
END     
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM prc_tst_bulk($$SELECT a AS name, b AS nome, c AS gender FROM tbl$$)
```

You cannot mix plain and dynamic SQL the way you tried to do it. The whole statement is either all dynamic or all plain SQL. So I am building one dynamic statement to make this work. You may be interested in the chapter about [executing dynamic commands in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

The aggregate function `count()` returns `bigint`, but you had `rowcount` defined as `integer`, so you need an explicit cast `::int` to make this work.

I use [dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) to avoid quoting hell.

**However**, is this supposed to be a **honeypot for [SQL injection](https://bobby-tables.com/)** attacks or are you seriously going to use it? For your very private and secure use, it might be ok-ish - though I wouldn't even trust myself with a function like that. If there is any possible access for untrusted users, such a function is a loaded footgun. It's impossible to make this secure.

Craig (a sworn enemy of SQL injection) might get a light stroke when he sees what you forged from [his answer to your preceding question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16290228/939860). :)

The query itself seems rather odd, btw. The two `SELECT` terms might be merged into one. But that's beside the point here.

Comment: I actually think this kind of thing is *less* bad than accepting unchecked params. If you're accepting whole raw SQL statements you already know your inputs have to come from an utterly trusted source or a source with the same priv level the function is executing as. Now, if it the function was `SECURITY DEFINER` too...

Comment: @CraigRinger: All in all, I hope I didn't completely misquote you with my remark. In which case I should remove it.

Comment: Nah, it's all good. It still gives me the twitches I assure you.